# Displaying values at legend level Histogram Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I searched a lot but I can not find how to display the values ​​at the legend level in a histogram. Either a software limit, or there are tips to do it so I need help.

The image below shows what I wanted to achieve in this link :
[enter link description here](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1902969/logiciels/solutions-d-entreprise/business-intelligence/qlikview/affichage-valeurs-niveau-legende-histogramme-qlikview/)

Answer (score 0):

A work around if possible is to use set analysis. (this will be best if the dimension only contains the 4 rows Familla A - D.

Create a single expression for each Familla.
Then label the expression the Familla x & its break down in percentage.
Alternatively create these as variables and then use the variables.

Answer (score 0):

there is no sense in showing numbers on legend when you have more than one dimension - this is why it will not show this option.

best solution: create a pie chart from the first dimension and narrow its' view to show only the legend, then just put it on the bar chart. (disable the legend of the bar chart - make sure to use "persistent colors" in both charts)